# Mongoose findById callback returns null despite existence of record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm confused with this. The `err` is valid if the record exists. Oppositely, the `err` is invalid if the record doesn't exist.

However, the `article` is always null, although the record is existent in database.

```
router.get("/:id", function (req, res) {
    Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, article) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(`Error: ${err}`);
        } else {
            //Print out "null"
            console.log(article);
            
            //Error occur
            Article.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, {$set:{views: article.views + 1}});
            res.render("showArticle", { article: article});
        }
    });
});
```

Article model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    views: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `_id` is `ObjectId` type and in that case you need to cast `req.params.id` from string to `ObjectId`.

Comment: try to `console.log(req.params.id)` do u get the required `id`?

Comment: @ShivamSood console.log(req.params.id) works fine, it prints out "5f34e1284e6d92173cda93bc".

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours, OK... it's silly of me.
I haven't given the third parameter in mongoose.model.

Change:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);
```

To

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema, "Article");
```

I found that mongoose.prototype.model will automatically add a "s" at the end of the model name if there isn't collection name, which means, the `Article` collection will be named to `Articles`